# tf.gather_nd without "flattening" shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I'm still playing around with tensorflow and been trying to use the gather_nd op, but the return value is not in the shape/format I want...

```
Input Tensor: - shape: (2, 7, 4) 
array([[[ 0., 0., 1., 2.],
        [ 0., 0., 2., 2.],
        [ 0., 0., 3., 3.],
        [ 0., 0., 4., 3.],
        [ 0., 0., 5., 4.],
        [ 0., 0., 6., 4.],
        [ 0., 0., 7., 5.]],
       [[ 1., 1., 0., 2.],
        [ 1., 2., 0., 2.],
        [ 1., 3., 0., 3.],
        [ 1., 4., 0., 3.],
        [ 1., 5., 0., 4.],
        [ 1., 6., 0., 5.],
        [ 1., 7., 0., 5.]]], dtype=float32) 

Indices returned by tf.where op: - shape: (3, 2) 
array([[0, 0], 
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]]) 

tf.gather results: (shape = [3, 4])
array([[ 0., 0., 1., 2.],
       [ 0., 0., 2., 2.],
       [ 1., 1., 0., 2.]], dtype=float32)

desired results: = (2, sparse, 4)
array([[[ 0., 0., 1., 2.],
        [ 0., 0., 2., 2.]],
       [[ 1., 1., 0., 2.]]], dtype=float32)
```

What's the best way to achieve this, keeping in mind that tf.where = dynamic shapes and no guarantees of shape consistency across the 2nd dimension (axis=1)?

NB: Ignore this question - See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think its a Tensorflow version problem. In my version (1.2.1), I get the exact desired output from your inputs. However, I also tried the following code according to the older version.

```
import tensorflow as tf

indices = [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3]],
           [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3]],
           [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 3]]]

params =  [[[ 0., 0., 1., 2.],
            [ 0., 0., 2., 2.],
            [ 0., 0., 3., 3.],
            [ 0., 0., 4., 3.],
            [ 0., 0., 5., 4.],
            [ 0., 0., 6., 4.],
            [ 0., 0., 7., 5.]],
           [[ 1., 1., 0., 2.],
            [ 1., 2., 0., 2.],
            [ 1., 3., 0., 3.],
            [ 1., 4., 0., 3.],
            [ 1., 5., 0., 4.],
            [ 1., 6., 0., 5.],
            [ 1., 7., 0., 5.]]]

output = tf.gather_nd(params, indices)

with tf.Session()as sess:
    print (sess.run(output))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the idiocy of my question.

```
# of tuples when 1st dim is 0    !=   # of tuples when 1st dim is 1
```

I'm not sure that what I'm asking is feasible ...